# Where are global variables which are static stored in memory?

Tags: c, memory

In C,the global variables are stored in data segment.But I have no clue where will static variables which are global get stored?

```
static int num;   //where will this variable get stored in memory?
int main(){
   //code 

}
```

Comment: Likely to be either optimized out, or stored in the same place a non-`static` version would be. The details are implementation-dependent

Comment: They're stored in memory somewhere. Probably. Or maybe not if the compiler is set to optimize away unused variables, like in this case where `num` is never used, or if the value never changes and it's able to be inlined as a constant. Why is this a concern?

Answer (score 4):

There are various places these variables may be stored, the standard does not mandate any particular storage location. Depending on situation they may even be stored in read-only memory (if not modified) or not at all (if not used). It is even not required that the location need to be fixed (or single).

The only requirement the standard puts regarding storage is that the variable has to keep it's value across function calls.

However a normal approach would be to place these together with the global variables. The only thing that differs static variables from global are the scope of the symbols. However note that this is only one possibility and I can imagine other reasonable solutions.

To get a more precise answer you need to know what platform and toolchain you are using.

Comment: "the standard does not mandate any particular storage location" +1 for pointing out that the question he asks is actually not subject of C, so he is either asking a question he doesn't want to ask, or expressing it wrong. Either way, you just answered what I had done otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the data segment of memory.